# Mysql Result 2d array to 1d Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a query that returns a 2d array, but would like it to return a 1d array of results. Given:

```
sql = "SELECT `id` FROM things WHERE other_id = 8"
ids = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a
```

`ids` is then equal to

`[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[9]....]`

I was using `map` to create a new array, but it was terribly slow with more than 5000 records. What is the fastest method of obtaining the following format:

`[1,2,3,4,5,9...]`

Comment: Why do you need **an array**, is it really necessary? Because if you only need a collection of `id`s to iterate on, or build a subquery, there are far better ways of doing this. Just trying to help, even if that's a bit beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do as

```
sql = "SELECT `id` FROM things WHERE other_id = 8"
ids = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a.flatten
```

More Rails way is to use [`#pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) as below :-

```
Thing.where(other_id: 8).pluck(:id)
```

Comment: @japed Hehehe.. Chill :-)

Comment: Yeah, `pluck` is the way to go here.

Comment: I'm not so sure he actually has a model defined, but we'll find that out shortly ._. If that's the case, you might want to add some references on how to generate and deal with a Rails model.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use the `execute` statement? Use an `ActiveRecord` model.

```
Thing.where(other_id: 8).pluck(:id)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your models and associations are set up correctly, i.e.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :other
end

class Other < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things
end
```

you can use [`ids`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-ids):

```
Thing.where(other_id: 8).ids  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9 ...]
```

or, coming from `Other`:

```
Other.find(8).things.ids      #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9 ...]
```

or:

```
Other.find(8).thing_ids       #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9 ...]
```

Comment: `thing_ids` is the cute one.. :D